# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled C# stack

Tags: c#, string, stack, arguments, substring

I have a problem at the line String fromIndexString = topStiva.Substring(topStivaLength + 1, topStiva.Length); . I shows that topStiva.Length is out or range.

The code is as follows:

String actiuneRezultata(String topStiva, String cuvIntr) {

```
        int index = -1;

        String primulCharCuvIntr = cuvIntr.Substring(0, 1);

        if (primulCharCuvIntr.Equals("+") == true)
            primulCharCuvIntr = "\\" + primulCharCuvIntr;

        else
            if (primulCharCuvIntr.Equals("*") == true)
                primulCharCuvIntr = "\\" + primulCharCuvIntr;

        else
            if (primulCharCuvIntr.Equals("*") == true)
                primulCharCuvIntr = "\\" + primulCharCuvIntr;

        else
            if (primulCharCuvIntr.Equals("*") == true)
                primulCharCuvIntr = "\\" + primulCharCuvIntr;

        else
            if (primulCharCuvIntr.Equals("*") == true)
                primulCharCuvIntr = "\\" + primulCharCuvIntr;

        for (int i = 0; i < ta.Length; i++) {

            if (ta[i].CompareTo(primulCharCuvIntr) == 0) {

                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        int topStivaLength = topStiva.Length - 1;

        while (topStiva[topStivaLength] >= '0' && topStiva[topStivaLength] <= 9)
            topStivaLength--;

        String fromIndexString = topStiva.Substring(topStivaLength + 1, topStiva.Length);
        int fromIndex = int.Parse(fromIndexString);

        if (index < 0)
            return "Nu face parte din gramatica!";
        else
            return tabela[fromIndex][index];

    }
```

The value topStiva is gets it from the call actiuneRezultata(stivaAPD.Peek().ToString(), another_value)

I saw that in stivaAPD I am geeting after push some values. So why is it that is out of range? Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) is the length of the desired substring. You seem to be calling it as if it were instead the (exclusive) end index of the substring. Try calling the following so that your length is equal to the distance to the end index of the string.

```
topStiva.Substring(topStivaLength+1, topStiva.Length - (topStivaLength+1));
```

Comment: Thanks ceykooo, I looked at your proposition I saw my mistake, I managed to solved it another way. But now it show my an error at int fromIndex = int.Parse(fromIndexString);. It says that Input string was not in a correct format. !

Comment: Try printing out `fromIndexString`, cause it seems like it does not actually contain an int, like you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

If topStivaLength is -1, this `(topStiva[topStivaLength]` will cause an exception.

If topStivaLength is 0 and topStiva is an empty string, this `(topStiva[topStivaLength]` will cause an exception.

Next time indicate exactly on what line you are getting the exception.